# nodejs promise async await sequential execution

Tags: node.js

How to get demo() to execute sequentially.

```js
demo()

async function demo() {
        doAll()
        console.log("I DO NOT print sequentially");
}

async function doAll() {
  var number = await getNumber();
  var double = await doubleWithTimeout(number);
  console.log(number,double)
}

async function getNumber() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var a = 2;
        resolve(a);
    });
}

async function doubleWithTimeout(x) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(x * 2);
        }, 2  );
    });
}
```

**Result:**
I do NOT print sequentially
2 4

**Expected Result:**
2 4
I do print sequentially

I was hoping i can get away with the below code, but you can't have await within a promise:

```
async function demo() {
        await doAll()
        console.log("i execute without waiting");
}

async function doAll() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var number = await getNumber();
        var double = await doubleWithTimeout(number);
        console.log(number, double)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just take your original code and put `await` in front of `doAll();`:

```js
demo()

async function demo() {
        await doAll(); // Added await here
        console.log("I DO NOT print sequentially");
}

async function doAll() {
  var number = await getNumber();
  var double = await doubleWithTimeout(number);
  console.log(number,double)
}

async function getNumber() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var a = 2;
        resolve(a);
    });
}

async function doubleWithTimeout(x) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(x * 2);
        }, 2  );
    });
}
```

Every function that is declared `async` (including `doAll`) returns a Promise. If the function body returns something other than a Promise, like `doAll` which returns `undefined`, the value is wrapped in an immediately resolved Promise by the async declaration.

As an aside, you said "but you can't have await within a promise", which is not correct. You just can't use await inside a function that is not async. If you want to use await inside a Promise constructor callback, just declare it as async:

```
return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {

});
```

Comment: no way....i've been hitting my head against the wall and it was just that. thanks.

Comment: @raka Added another note. You can use `await` inside a Promise callback if you want.

Comment: @raka Also, because async wraps the returned value in a Promise. Your `getNumber` function could be rewritten as just `async function getNumber( ) { return 2; }` as has the same behaviour (returns a Promise resolved with the value `2`).

Comment: ah thanks. i didn't realize i could do "return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {...});". Also the example above was just to clarify the usage. I'm working on code that has way more logic than the getNumber function that's illustrated.